# Namespace name "Device" does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, geolocation, device

I have a problem using System.Device and can't find a solution

I'm developing a software and want to get the position of the device. By referencing the .NET Framework I want to use the `GeoCoordinateWatcher`.

In my code I included `System.Device.Location` and added two packages to the project (`GeoCoordinate` and `System.Device.Location.Portable`). While running and debugging the code in monodevelop no error occurs, but when I compile the code with mcs the error mentioned in the title occurs:

> Namespace name "Device" does not exist in the namespace

Im using a RasPi for coding and compiling.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please clarify: "I'm using RasPi" - does it means that your program runs on Raspberry Pi? If so - add tag [raspberry-pi]

Answer (score 0):

System.Device is not supported by Mono:
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class

Comment: I added https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Location.Portable/ and https://github.com/ghuntley/geocoordinate to the project. While debugging in monodevelop, everything is fine.

Comment: Is your dev machine windows? Are you using mono or msbuild to compile on your dev machine?